# split apache spark dataframe into multiple chunk dataframes for crossJoin acceleration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to split a spark dataframe into multiple dataframe,
this can be helpful in case of crossJoin to avoid stucking the cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just developed a new algorithm that split a whole dataframe into multiple dataframes, each chunk of dataframe can be processed alone without stucking the cluster (case of crossJoin)

all the algorithm and the code with example and explanation in this link :

https://medium.com/@djeddi.amin/split-spark-dataframe-into-multiple-small-dataframes-filter-approach-8f7ac36e12c5

feel free to contact me : djeddi.amin@gmail.com

```
#First : add incremental column 

df = df.withColumn("idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window().orderBy("idx")
df = df.withColumn("id", (F.row_number().over(w))).drop('idx')
df.show()


#second step : apply the algo ! 
desired_chunks = 3
cnt = df.count()
res = rows_number//desired_chunks
rem = rows_number%desired_chunks #modulo
iteration_rang = desired_chunks+1

for i in range(1, iteration_rang) :
    if (i == 1):
       #this will only calculate the first chunck
       df_part= df.filter(df.id.between(i, res))
       #process your df_part...
       df_part.show()

    if(i> 1 & i<iteration_rang):
       df_part= df.filter((df.id.between((res*(i-1)+1), res*i)))
       #process your df_part...
       df_part.show()

       if(rem != 0):
          if(i== rng-1):
             df_part= df.filter((df.id.between((res*(i)+1), cnt)))
             # process your df_part...
             df_part.show()
       else :
           continue
```